# ask user input for the multidimensional array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I want to take user input for my multi dimensional matrix. I tried this one but it didn't worked. :(

```
    int matrix[][] = new int [3][3];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i <=2 ; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j <=2 ; j++) {
            System.out.println("gir:");
            //String input = sc.nextLine();
            //double d = Double.parseDouble(input);

        }

    }

    double result = ((matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][2]) 
        + (matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][1]*matrix[0][2]) 
        + (matrix[2][0]*matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][2])) 
        - ((matrix[0][2]*matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][0]) 
        + (matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][1]*matrix[0][0]) 
        + (matrix[2][2]*matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0]));
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a problem description. Where is the part where you store the input from the ``Scanner`` to the array?

Comment: what do you wan't exactly and what stop you from doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You never store the input in your `matrix`. You are probably looking for

```
String input = sc.nextLine();
int a = Integer.parseInt(input);
matrix[i][j] = a;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works.

Answer (score -1):

You never actually put the double into your array.  A way to do that is

```
matrix[i][j] = d;
```

Comment: Only web as HTML/JS can be in the executable snippet, not Java